# Django syncdb fails at Applying auth.0001_initial

Tags: python, mysql, django, azure

I've created a Django App to be hosted on Azure so I'm using Python Tools for Visual Studio to develop the app. I created a model called Client in models.py in my root app. It's actually a modelform as the table columns are all linked to fields in a form I've created. I'm using MySQL and the connector is MySQLClient as I'm using Python 3.4. I ran `python manage.py syncdb` and the following was displayed:

```
Operations to perform:
 Synchronize unmigrated apps: staticfiles, messages, VSpace
 Apply all migrations: auth, sessions, contenttypes, sites
Synchronizing apps without migrations:
 Creating tables...
  Creating table VSpace_Client
  Running deferred SQL...
 Installing custom SQL...
Running migrations:
 Rendering model states... DONE
 Applying auth.0001_initial...Traceback (most recent call last):
```

That is where it fails. I was researching this and I came across something about creating a super user. I tried that but it fails as well after I've entered the credentials. Does anyone know why this is happening?

Edit 1:

Traceback:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Vinu\Google Drive\VVN Group\VSPace\VSpace Website\VSpace\VSpace\env\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\utils.py", line 62, in execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql)
  File "C:\Users\Vinu\Google Drive\VVN Group\VSPace\VSpace Website\VSpace\VSpace\env\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\mysql\base.py", line 124, in execute
    return self.cursor.execute(query, args)
  File "C:\Users\Vinu\Google Drive\VVN Group\VSPace\VSpace Website\VSpace\VSpace\env\lib\site-packages\MySQLdb\cursors.py", line 220, in execute
    self.errorhandler(self, exc, value)
  File "C:\Users\Vinu\Google Drive\VVN Group\VSPace\VSpace Website\VSpace\VSpace\env\lib\site-packages\MySQLdb\connections.py", line 36, in defaulterrorhandler
    raise errorvalue
  File "C:\Users\Vinu\Google Drive\VVN Group\VSPace\VSpace Website\VSpace\VSpace\env\lib\site-packages\MySQLdb\cursors.py", line 209, in execute
    r = self._query(query)
  File "C:\Users\Vinu\Google Drive\VVN Group\VSPace\VSpace Website\VSpace\VSpace\env\lib\site-packages\MySQLdb\cursors.py", line 371, in _query
    rowcount = self._do_query(q)
  File "C:\Users\Vinu\Google Drive\VVN Group\VSPace\VSpace Website\VSpace\VSpace\env\lib\site-packages\MySQLdb\cursors.py", line 335, in _do_query
    db.query(q)
  File "C:\Users\Vinu\Google Drive\VVN Group\VSPace\VSpace Website\VSpace\VSpace\env\lib\site-packages\MySQLdb\connections.py", line 280, in query
    _mysql.connection.query(self, query)
_mysql_exceptions.OperationalError: (1050, "Table 'auth_permission' already exists")

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Vinu\Google Drive\VVN Group\VSPace\VSpace Website\VSpace\VSpace\manage.py", line 17, in <module>
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "C:\Users\Vinu\Google Drive\VVN Group\VSPace\VSpace Website\VSpace\VSpace\env\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 338, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "C:\Users\Vinu\Google Drive\VVN Group\VSPace\VSpace Website\VSpace\VSpace\env\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 330, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "C:\Users\Vinu\Google Drive\VVN Group\VSPace\VSpace Website\VSpace\VSpace\env\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 393, in run_from_argv
    self.execute(*args, **cmd_options)
  File "C:\Users\Vinu\Google Drive\VVN Group\VSPace\VSpace Website\VSpace\VSpace\env\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 444, in execute
    output = self.handle(*args, **options)
  File "C:\Users\Vinu\Google Drive\VVN Group\VSPace\VSpace Website\VSpace\VSpace\env\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\commands\syncdb.py", line 25, in handle
    call_command("migrate", **options)
  File "C:\Users\Vinu\Google Drive\VVN Group\VSPace\VSpace Website\VSpace\VSpace\env\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 120, in call_command
    return command.execute(*args, **defaults)
  File "C:\Users\Vinu\Google Drive\VVN Group\VSPace\VSpace Website\VSpace\VSpace\env\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 444, in execute
    output = self.handle(*args, **options)
  File "C:\Users\Vinu\Google Drive\VVN Group\VSPace\VSpace Website\VSpace\VSpace\env\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\commands\migrate.py", line 221, in handle
    executor.migrate(targets, plan, fake=fake, fake_initial=fake_initial)
  File "C:\Users\Vinu\Google Drive\VVN Group\VSPace\VSpace Website\VSpace\VSpace\env\lib\site-packages\django\db\migrations\executor.py", line 110, in migrate
    self.apply_migration(states[migration], migration, fake=fake, fake_initial=fake_initial)
  File "C:\Users\Vinu\Google Drive\VVN Group\VSPace\VSpace Website\VSpace\VSpace\env\lib\site-packages\django\db\migrations\executor.py", line 148, in apply_migration
    state = migration.apply(state, schema_editor)
  File "C:\Users\Vinu\Google Drive\VVN Group\VSPace\VSpace Website\VSpace\VSpace\env\lib\site-packages\django\db\migrations\migration.py", line 115, in apply
    operation.database_forwards(self.app_label, schema_editor, old_state, project_state)
  File "C:\Users\Vinu\Google Drive\VVN Group\VSPace\VSpace Website\VSpace\VSpace\env\lib\site-packages\django\db\migrations\operations\models.py", line 59, in database_forwards
    schema_editor.create_model(model)
  File "C:\Users\Vinu\Google Drive\VVN Group\VSPace\VSpace Website\VSpace\VSpace\env\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\base\schema.py", line 286, in create_model
    self.execute(sql, params or None)
  File "C:\Users\Vinu\Google Drive\VVN Group\VSPace\VSpace Website\VSpace\VSpace\env\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\base\schema.py", line 111, in execute
    cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "C:\Users\Vinu\Google Drive\VVN Group\VSPace\VSpace Website\VSpace\VSpace\env\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\utils.py", line 79, in execute
    return super(CursorDebugWrapper, self).execute(sql, params)
  File "C:\Users\Vinu\Google Drive\VVN Group\VSPace\VSpace Website\VSpace\VSpace\env\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\utils.py", line 64, in execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "C:\Users\Vinu\Google Drive\VVN Group\VSPace\VSpace Website\VSpace\VSpace\env\lib\site-packages\django\db\utils.py", line 97, in __exit__
    six.reraise(dj_exc_type, dj_exc_value, traceback)
  File "C:\Users\Vinu\Google Drive\VVN Group\VSPace\VSpace Website\VSpace\VSpace\env\lib\site-packages\django\utils\six.py", line 658, in reraise
    raise value.with_traceback(tb)
  File "C:\Users\Vinu\Google Drive\VVN Group\VSPace\VSpace Website\VSpace\VSpace\env\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\utils.py", line 62, in execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql)
  File "C:\Users\Vinu\Google Drive\VVN Group\VSPace\VSpace Website\VSpace\VSpace\env\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\mysql\base.py", line 124, in execute
    return self.cursor.execute(query, args)
  File "C:\Users\Vinu\Google Drive\VVN Group\VSPace\VSpace Website\VSpace\VSpace\env\lib\site-packages\MySQLdb\cursors.py", line 220, in execute
    self.errorhandler(self, exc, value)
  File "C:\Users\Vinu\Google Drive\VVN Group\VSPace\VSpace Website\VSpace\VSpace\env\lib\site-packages\MySQLdb\connections.py", line 36, in defaulterrorhandler
    raise errorvalue
  File "C:\Users\Vinu\Google Drive\VVN Group\VSPace\VSpace Website\VSpace\VSpace\env\lib\site-packages\MySQLdb\cursors.py", line 209, in execute
    r = self._query(query)
  File "C:\Users\Vinu\Google Drive\VVN Group\VSPace\VSpace Website\VSpace\VSpace\env\lib\site-packages\MySQLdb\cursors.py", line 371, in _query
    rowcount = self._do_query(q)
  File "C:\Users\Vinu\Google Drive\VVN Group\VSPace\VSpace Website\VSpace\VSpace\env\lib\site-packages\MySQLdb\cursors.py", line 335, in _do_query
    db.query(q)
  File "C:\Users\Vinu\Google Drive\VVN Group\VSPace\VSpace Website\VSpace\VSpace\env\lib\site-packages\MySQLdb\connections.py", line 280, in query
    _mysql.connection.query(self, query)
django.db.utils.OperationalError: (1050, "Table 'auth_permission' already exists")
The Python REPL process has exited
```

Comment: Please add the Traceback

Comment: Hi Mark. Just added the traceback.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First off, try running `python manage.py migrate` instead of `syncdb`. If I remember correctly the `syncdb` command is being deprecated in favor of the `makemigrations` and `migrate` commands. Try that, and things should go better.

Related: what version of Django are you using?

Comment: Just tried it and it worked. I'm using Django V1.8.3.

Answer (score 1):

1. Delete all your files inside migrate folders.
2. Run: `python manage.py makemigrations`
3. Run: `python manage.py migrate`
4. Run: `python manage.py createsuperuser`

As JwM said `syncdb` is being deprecated, now use `makemigrations` and `migrate`

Comment: Hi 4ndr3. Where do I find the migrate folders?

Comment: I just ran the makemigrations and migrate commands and it worked fine now.

Answer (score 1):

The `auth_permissions` table already exists in your DB, but the migration thinks it does not. Try to fake the migration to get past this point.

```
./manage.py migrate auth --fake
```

Comment: Just ran the command. I get the following error: django.db.utils.ProgrammingError: (1146, "Table 'vspacedb.django_site' doesn't exist"). I'm not sure why this table is necessary.

Comment: Mark, please can you explain the logic behind --fake. It seems like a debugging technique. I'm new to Django so I'm not aware of this.

Comment: Fake is a way of skipping a migration (not executing the SQL) if the database already has that state. See here: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/django-admin/#django-admin-option---fake